# Filtering out image/css/js requests from access logs in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to filter out any image/css/js requests from my access logs. I created a filter (LoggingFilter) and set the conditionUnless attribute in server.xml but I must be missing a step because requests for image/css/js files still show up in the logs. Can someone give me a hint as to what I'm missing?

Here's the code -

LoggingFilter.java

```
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter 
{ 

@Override 
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException 
{ 

} 

@Override 
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
{ 
    chain.doFilter(request, response); 
    if(response.getContentType() != null) 
    { 
        if (response.getContentType().contains("image") || 
                response.getContentType().contains("css") || 
                response.getContentType().contains("javascript")) 
        { 
            request.setAttribute("doNotLog", "noLog"); 
        } 
    } 
} 

@Override 
public void destroy() 
{ 

} 
}
```

Here's what I have in web.xml

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.shop.famos.filters.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the tomcat settings I have -

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" conditionUnless="doNotLog" pattern="common"/>
```

Btw, i'm using tomcat 7

Also, wanted to mention i did see this post [Tomcat 7: Filter access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599257/tomcat-7-filter-access-log) which says that one must subclass "org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" to implement a more specific filter. Is this the only way? Or can it be achieved using a Filter like I have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the step I was missing. I picked up a good book from Amazon "Apache Tomcat 7" which helped me realize that Tomcat has it's own built in filters that one can use to inspect and modify incoming requests. Initially I had my filter as part of my web project which does no good because my filter needed to be at the server level so that the request attribute I was setting would be seen by the access log.

So basically I put my compiled class in a jar and put it in Tomcat's class path, put my filter definition and mapping in Tomcat's web.xml file, restarted Tomcat and went to the home page of my site and sure enough any requests for js, image or css files did not end up in the logs.